# css extend border to include image

Tags: css, html

I have an html div with id `information`. Ideally, the border would extend to the bottom of the image in the div.

```
<div id="information">
    <img src="newtroot-256.png" id="newtroot256" style="float:left;"/>
    <span style="position:relative;left:10px;">
        Hi! My name is Nicki.
    </span>
</div>
```

for html and

```
div#information {
    color:burlywood;
    margin-left:2em;
    margin-right:2em;
    border:2px solid lime;
    border-radius:25px;
    background-color:rgba(85,107,47,0.75);
    padding:10px;
    background-opacity:0.5;
}
```

for the css are the relevant parts. The output is

[image]

but I want to border to include the image. How would I do this is css/html. I do not wish to incude javascript, but if it's the only soulution, I'll take it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the image is floated, it is removed from normal flow. To make the parent expand, the float must be [cleared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear).

```
#information:after {
    content: '';
    display: table; 
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes… but he must have applied a float as that's what the image shows.

Comment: Then, it was a `float:right` @GCyrillus. I changed it to `float:top` forgetting that it didn't exist.

Comment: Yep @GCyrillus, I will take that in to account in the future.

Comment: can you edit your question so code match with question and screen  :), then i can remove my answer and some comments